# Access contents of bindingsource.Current when source is an IQueryable object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, bindingsource

Currently my repository returns an `IQueryable` object that lists the data from my DB and I bind this to a `BindingSource` for use in a grid:

```
public void BindTo(IQueryable elements)
{
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    source.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(source_CurrentChanged);
    source.DataSource = elements;

    elementNavigator.BindingSource = source;
    elementGridView.DataSource = source;
}
```

This works great.  However I am wanting to do some stuff when a user clicks an row in the grid.  I'm struggling to identify the element that the user is selecting.  I have the following:

In my view:

```
private void source_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _presenter.ElementChanged(sender, e);
}
```

In my presenter:

```
public void ElementChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource source = (BindingSource)sender;
    // Here I need to get the ID of the selected element in the source.Current property.
    // HOW?
}
```

This seems to work ok - and I can see when debugging that `source.Current` contains the data:

```
? source.Current
{ BodyId = 1, IsInUse = true, IsValid = true, CreateDate = {04/07/2006 09:31:59}, LastUpdateDate = {04/07/2006 09:31:59}, StatusDescShort = "Exist" ... }
BodyId: 1
CreateDate: {04/07/2006 09:31:59}
IsInUse: true
IsValid: true
LastUpdateDate: {04/07/2006 09:31:59}
StatusDescShort: "Exist"
```

but I am at a loss as how I might access the value of `BodyId`.  I've a feeling I'm missing something really obvious here (not the first time).

Comment: Hmm Reading a few things I'm starting to think I'm fundamentally wrong and shouldn't be using IQueryable at all and instead should be binding to a List.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised you're  not using  something like `IQueryable<MyType>`.

Because then it would be a simple matter of casting:  `source.Current as MYType`

And maybe eliminate an in-between DataRowView

Comment: I think you are right - but I am doing a further query on the elements before passing to my bindingsource and the resultant object is an anonymous type.  As commented above I think I will refactor to use a List instead as I am also struggling with IQueryable not supporting sorting on the grid.  Thanks though

Comment: @Martin: A List containing an anonymous type will suffer the same problems. You'll need reflection to get at the properties.

Comment: You are probably right.  However this particular problem has been solved for the moment and a couple of other issues also so I will cross that bridge when I come to it.